# redirecting from non www to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two websites - I have made htaccess file same for both of them (each has diffent links of course). They are same. My goal is to redirect from non www to www. Now it works for the first website. For the second one it works too but only on /index, the rest of pages doesn't redirect. Any idea what the problem might be? I believe there is no mistake in htaccess as I checked it and they should be completely the same.

Files - it works for AAA, doesn't for BBB. Htaccess code below:

```
AAA SITE:



RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

DirectoryIndex index.html


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aaa\.net
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.aaa.net/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.aaa.net/404page

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType text/css A604800
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A604800
ExpiresByType text/html A60
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>




BBB SITE:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^domains/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/domains/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) domains/%2/$1 [DPI]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

DirectoryIndex index.html


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .html extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bbb\.net
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bbb.net/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.bbb.net/404page

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A600
ExpiresByType text/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType application/javascript A604800
ExpiresByType text/css A604800
ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
ExpiresByType image/png A604800
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A604800
ExpiresByType text/html A60
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't let you? Paste the code in a code block

Comment: at least some lines from htaccess related to it. The first one AAA works, the second one BBB doesn't

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aaa\.net
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.aaa.net/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bbb\.net
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.bbb.net/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Comment: it says I don't have reputation to send more than 2 links

Comment: Paste your code in your question, not as a comment

Comment: Okay but you should put the code actually *in* your question

Comment: Yeah but I told you it doesn't let me because I don't have reputation to post more than 2 links and there are links in htaccess...thanks for updating for me tho

Answer (score 0):

For both sites (`AAA` & `BBB`), use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This translates as:

- For every `URI` which does not start with `www.`, rewrite the `URI` as:

  http://www.[the-rest-of-the-domain][/the-rest-of-the-uri]

Comment: I tried, however I am not sure if this is the final code I should put in? Should I add AAA or BBB somehow? What should I replace with this? Basically whatever I tried with this it said the site cannot be loaded because of too many redirects.

Comment: My apologies. The rewrite condition I wrote originally was too broad. I have modified it. It should work now, so please test it again.